# Debug Gradle's parallel mode

Tags: gradle

We are trying Gradle for our very large and complex enterprise app. We are using multi project build structure and are very excited with Gradle's parallel execution feature.

Our codebase is structured in domain layers like this:

UI modules (~20) -> shared ui -> domain -> dao -> framework

Dependencies are uni directional and build happens bottom up.

Unfortunately we are not seeing a big boost in our build times. Its pretty much same as what we were getting with ant before.

Looking at the execution sequence of tasks in parallel mode few things doesn't look right.
Our expectation is Gradle will run tasks in sequence initially when it is building core layers. So after it assembles framework, dao, domain and shared ui, it should kick everything else in parallel.

But execution sequence we are seeing is somewhat like this:

framework.assemble -> dao.assemble -> domain.assemble -> shared.ui.assemble -> Other UI modules.assmble (in parallel) -> war -> Other UI.check + shared.ui.check + dao.check (in parallel) -> domain.check -> framework.check

Bottleneck is at the end when it is running checks for domain and framework in sequence and not in parallel. These 2 modules are the biggest modules for us with around 12k unit tests and they take around 4 mins to run.

We spent lot of time looking at the dependencies using gradle tasks --all and test task for these modules are completely independent and there is nothing that should hold off their execution.

We are wondering if this is a known issue or is there a way to enable some extra debugging in Gradle to get more insight as how Gradle determines execution order with parallel mode. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

As of Gradle 1.4, parallel task execution is (intentionally) constrained in a few ways. In particular, the set of tasks executing at any time won't contain two tasks belonging to the same project. This will be improved over time. I'm not aware of any debugging aids other than what you get from the logs (e.g. with `--debug`).

Note that parallel test execution is a separate feature. If you have a lot of tests in the same project, `test.maxParallelForks = x` with x > 1 should show a noticeable speedup. The value for x is best determined experimentally. A good starting point is the number of physical cores on the machine (e.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() / 2`).

Comment: ** In particular, the set of tasks executing at any time won't contain two tasks belonging to the same project.**  

That's very useful info. So, what is the granularity for tasks for a project in parallel mode? Is check considered a task or test or pmd are tasks? And how does it differ between root project and sub projects?  

Unfortunately, for us ** maxParallelForks ** doesn't work at all. We have tried setting it to minimum useful value 2 and build fails all over the place. It hits "Too many open files in system" error on OSX pretty soon.

Comment: The granularity of a task is always the same. All of `check`, `test`, `pmd` are tasks (actually I think it's `pmdMain`). No difference between root project and subprojects. Of course, task graph is taken into account for parallelization, but additionally the constraint that no two tasks from same project can run in parallel is enforced. Which Gradle version are you using? If you hit a problem with `maxParallelForks`, please report at http://forums.gradle.org. Also try to increase the maximum number of open files (should be easy on *nix).